# Understanding relationships with a table and itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to provide a demo table. The important columns are `Fname`, `Lname`, `SSN` and `SuperSSN`.

| fname | lname | ssn | superssn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ahmed | Ali | 112233 | 223344 |
| Hanaa | Sobhy | 123456 | 223344 |
| Kamel | Mohamed | 223344 | 321654 |
| Amr | Omran | 321654 | NULL |
| Edward | Hanna | 512463 | 321654 |
| Maged | Raoof | 521634 | 968574 |
| Mariam | Adel | 669955 | 512463 |
| Noha | Mohamed | 968574 | 321654 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Now, the task is:

> Find all names of the employees who directly supervised by Kamel Mohamed.

I couldn't wrap my head around a table with a relationship with itself.

This is my best solution, but I feel like I can do better:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE superSSN = 223344
```

which is correct, but I don't want to look in the table and get Kamel's SSN. Is there a shortcut that I can access the employees that have Kamel as their supervisor without directly getting Kamel's SSN?
If so, please share!

Comment: You can do a _self join_.

Comment: But, a _self join_ is basically the same as "look in the table and get Kamel's SSN" 

Comment: @Luuk, yes, but having the dbms doing the work for you.

Comment: Ah yes the typical "everyone has exactly one (not more or less) SSN, that noone else has" fallacy... SSN is just a bit of data about a person, it does *not* uniquely identify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know supervisor's name, then you could - for example - use a subquery:

```
select *
from employee
where superSSN = (select SSN
                  from employee
                  where fname = 'Kamel'
                 );
```

or a self-join:

```
select a.*
from employee a join employee b on a.superSSN = b.ssn
where b.fname = 'Kamel';
```

Comment: if there are multiple Kamels, the forst query would give an error

Comment: There's only one Kamel, of course. Always. @nbk. Now seriously: query just shows how to avoid Kamel's SSN. One could add last name into it (but there's no guarantee that only one "Kamel Mohamed" works there). Ideally, you'd use **unique** identifier, which is a SSN, but Yousef wants to avoid it as - I presume - it is easier to memorize "Kamel" being a supervisor than 6 or 7 digits number that represents the same Kamel person. Anyway, yes, I agree, your comment is valid, thank you for that.

Comment: i know that but for users that have no clue about sql,  you get an error, so more explanation would help improve the answer